# How to @Autowire a BeanFactory in a Managed Bean(JSF)

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

When I need a BeanFactory in a bean managed by Spring, I use:

```
private @Autowired BeanFactory factory;
```

How can I achive this in a Managed Bean?
I have tried:

```
 @ManagedProperty(value = "#{BeanFactory}")
private BeanFactory beanFactory;// (the property has getters and setters)
```

But the property is null.

I have an EL resolver in faces-config:

```
<el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

Thank you and sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Why do you need a `BeanFactory` in general you should avoid using the `BeanFactory` directly.

Comment: Is there any better way to create a bean?

Comment: Why do you need the `BeanFactory` to create a bean? You can simply use  `@ManagedProperty` to get the desired bean from the applicationcontext!

Comment: How can one accomplish to get a prototype bean in a way by not using the `BeanFactory` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `@ManagedProperty` markup may have been the problem, in that `(value = "#{BeanFactory}")` should have been `(value = "#{beanFactory}")`, unless your BeanFactory class was specifically named "BeanFactory" in the @ManagedBean markup within it.

By default, beans annotated with @ManagedBean will be mapped to their class name, but the first character will be lower case, e.g.: "BeanFactory" becomes mapped as "beanFactory", FooBean becomes "fooBean".